# Netlogo GIS Extension copying polygon feature to patches conversion error

Tags: gis, netlogo, arcgis, agent-based-modeling

I have a polygon feature data set of emergency service zones for Tucson Metropolitan Area and want to copy the polygon attributes to the patches. The code is only creating/coloring these patches.(Picture shown below).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgwut.png)

I want to create a patch that covers the entire emergency service zone (second picture shown below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDFnU.jpg)

Here is my code. I tried using the vertex of the polygon and was not successful. I tried using the center of the polygon and I came out with a different output than what I want.

My code is:

```
to setup-gis ;; copy gis features to patches
  clear-patches 
  show "Loading patches..." 
  gis:apply-coverage ESZs-dataset "STATION_NO" emergency-zone
  foreach gis:feature-list-of ESZs-dataset [ feature ->  
    ask patches [
    let centroid1 gis:location-of gis:centroid-of feature 
    ask patch item 0 centroid1 item 1 centroid1  [
      set emergency-zone gis:property-value feature "STATION_NO"
      set pcolor yellow
      ;show emergency-zone
        ]
   ]
   ]
  show "Done"
end
```

Comment: to setup-gis ;; copy gis features to patches
  clear-patches 
  show "Loading patches..." 
  gis:apply-coverage ESZs-dataset "STATION_NO" emergency-zone
  foreach gis:feature-list-of ESZs-dataset [ feature ->  
    ask patches [
    let centroid1 gis:location-of gis:centroid-of feature 
    ask patch item 0 centroid1 item 1 centroid1  [
      set emergency-zone gis:property-value feature "STATION_NO"
      set pcolor yellow
      ;show emergency-zone
        ]
   ]
   ]
  show "Done"
end

Comment: for some reason I can't post the code in a correct format. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach gis:feature-list-of ESZs-dataset [ ;for each polygon
 polygon ->
 ask patches gis:intersecting polygon [
  set emergency-zone (gis:property-value polygon "STATION_NO")
  set pcolor yellow     ]
]
```

If I understood well, you want to give attribute values to all the patches that intersecting corresponding polygon.. So you should ask patches that are intersecting with `ask patches gis:intersecting`